# Замыкания в Swift это значимый или ссылочный тип?

Tags: swift4

Замыкания в Swift являются ссылочным (reference) типом или значимым (value)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Swift 4, как и во всех остальных версиях, замыкания (closures) являются ссылочным  (reference) типом.

Также замыкания "захватывают и держат" ссылки на переменные из контекста в котором находятся, что может приводить к retain cycle.

Подробнее в [документации](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html)